# How do I add two icons to StandardListItem

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have been stuck on this point for a while now. Can you please tell me how I can add two icons on a StandardListItem (currently my view is an xml type). My xml view code is shown below:

```
    <List
            id="nameList" 
            select="selectNameList" 
            mode="{device>/listMode}" 
            noDataText="{i18n>masterListNoDataText}" 
            growing="true" 
            growingScrollToLoad="false"
            growingThreshold="{ui>/listPageSize}"
            items="{/components}">
            <items
                id="masterList">


                    <StandardListItem
                    id = "standardListItemID"
                    class="draggable_list"
                    title="{name}"
                    type="{ui>/listItemType}"
                    press="pressNameListItem"
                    icon="sap-icon://wrench"
                    iconInset="true"
                    description="{type}"
                    activeIcon="true">

                    <Image></Image>

                </StandardListItem> 


            </items>
```

The problem here is that I can't add two icons in the properties of the StandardListItem element. The wrench icon is shown on the left side of the list, but it appears that I have no way of adding another icon on the right hand side :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't add more icons to **StandardListItem**. Use **[CustomListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.CustomListItem/about)** instead.